# File upload Codeigniter and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

controller

```
function do_test()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './images';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '10000';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $confit['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('file', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $test = $this->input->post('file');
    var_dump($test); //var dump return : string(21) "C:\fakepath\truth.jpg"

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($test))
    {
        echo "no";
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        echo "yes";
    }
}
```

form

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('home/do_test', array( 'id' => 'skill-form-test' ) );?>

    <input type="file" name="userfile" id="file" size="20" />

    <br /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="upload" />

    </form>
```

jquery

```
$('#skill-form-test').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post(base_url + "index.php/home/do_test", { file : $("#file").val()  }, function(data)
        {
            }, "json");
    alert ( $("#file").val() + "-" + base_url ); //This alerts: C:\fakepath\truth.jpg-http://siteurl.com/
});
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here. In simple words, what's the question?

Comment: Why is the image file not uploading?

Comment: @ciprian why are using `json` datatype for uploading images?

Comment: No errors in firebug. @Raminson I am not just uploading an image, I am also sending some other information. The image upload is optional. But I couldn't get the file to upload so I decided to start from scratch.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Update**: The fix is for CodeIgniter v3 and may not work on the recent version.

Just change

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($test))
```

to

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
```

will fix the issue.

Hope this helps you. Thank you!!